# Html+CSS fix menu by percent to children

Tags: html, css

I want to create a menu with the width of 100%.

Children width is auto, but i want fixed to parent

And I don't set `width` of children since their texts has different lengths.

Sample:

[image]

I use this CSS but it doesn't work in a desirable way:

```
#menu a {
       padding:10px calc(100% / 5);
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this trick to do just that

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
}
```

Read full article to better understand it [responsive fluid width variable item navigation css](https://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-fluid-width-variable-item-navigation-css/)

Comment: This create equal width for children as width:calc(100%7). i want set width to children by text width

Comment: no it doesn't give equal width to children. Like I said read the full article. You'll find what you're looking for. They're doing it with different ways. Hope it helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Set this to the parent :

`.parent{
    display:flex;
  }`

2. Set this to the children:

`.children{
    flex:1;
    text-align:center;
  }`

Comment: This create equal width for children as width:calc(100%7). i want set width to children by text width

Comment: oh, Please remove the `flex:1`? and add `width:100%` to parent

Comment: `flex: 1 auto` please.